# PowerShell script to launch 4 IE windows using different AD account credentials

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, automation, credentials

Why won't this simple PowerShell script launch 4 IE windows using different AD account credentials which are embedded into the script?

```
$users = ('testaccount1','testaccount2','testaccount3','testaccount4')
$password = 'password'    
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $username = ('domainname\' + $user)
    Write-Host $username
    $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
    Start-Process -FilePath "c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -LoadUserProfile -Credential $cred -ArgumentList "http://websiteaddress.com"
}
```

When I run it, I get this error, but the IE file path is correct:

```
domainname\testaccount1
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The directory name is invalid.
At C:\Users\username\Downloads\Launch IE as multiple users for testing.ps1:12 char:2
+     Start-Process -FilePath "c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -Load     ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Can someone please explain why the above script gives this error?  I'm using PowerShell 3.

Note: this line will launch IE & go to the specified website URL so I know the IE file path & directory name is valid:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe " "http://www.google.com"
```

Comment: your code looks ok so remove all arguments from 2nd last line to turn `Start-Process -FilePath "c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -LoadUserProfile -Credential $cred -ArgumentList "http://websiteaddress.com"` into `Start-Process -FilePath "c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"` to see if IE launches OK. if it does then keep adding arguments one by one to identify the culprit.

Comment: I replaced $users & $password with my account details, and the script works fine - IE launches OK.  If I then change $users to e.g. testaccount1 then I get the same error as before i.e. "Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The directory name is invalid."  If I change the script so I have to manually enter the credentials to use, and I enter testaccount1 & its password, then IE launches using those credentials.  I'm stumped now & don't know how to resolve this :-( NB: This is for simultaneous SharePoint 2013 testing using different AD credentials.

Comment: perhaps these accounts don't have a right to logon locally? check local security policy, or just try to login with test credentials to the box you are running the tests on. if folders corresponding to test usernames don't exist in _C:\Users_ then that will be it

Comment: The folders corresponding to test usernames already exist in C:\Users on my laptop.  The test usernames & passwords work in SharePoint 2013 - this was tested via holding shift & right clicking on IE in the Win7 taskbar & selecting "Run as different user".  I checked Resultant Set of Policy (Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Allow log on locally) & it's set to Not Defined.  If I d/click on this to show its properties then 'Define these policy settings' / 'Add User or Group" / 'Remove' are all greyed out.  I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: What happens when you run `Start-Process -FilePath "c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -Credential $cred -ArgumentList "http://websiteaddress.com"` without _-LoadUserProfile_